# can't call the player

Tags: python, pygame

im trying to make something like a game its a spaceship game i have the pictures spaceship.png and player.png but i cant see the player i can only see the icon and a black screen

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("1st game")
icon = pygame.image.load("Spaceship.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 600


def player():
    screen.blit(playerImg, (playerX, playerY))


running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    player()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

but it only shows a black screen and it doesn't show the player

Comment: nevermind my mistake was that i had to make it like this

Comment: `PlayerY = 370 PlayerX  = 480

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: have check the path of your `.png`file?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the screen is 800x600. The players y coordinate is 600. Hence the player is out of the window at the bottom.
Change the coordinate of the player:

<s>`playerY = 600`</s>

```py
playerY = 480
```